# Debian 8 - Run scripts after boot

Tags: debian, ubuntu, virtualbox

I've tried run some scripts after boot via `/etc/rc.local`.

#### /etc/rc.local

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
/home/startup.sh

exit 0
```

#### /home/startup.sh

```
mount -t vboxsf test /home/test
```

#### Here is the result on boot

[image]

#### Here is the output of `systemctl status rc-local.service`

```
rc-local.service - /etc/rc.local Compatibility
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service; static)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2016-02-07 22:48:23 ICT; 18min ago
  Process: 432 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 07 22:48:23 debian rc.local[432]: /sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such device
Feb 07 22:48:23 debian systemd[1]: rc-local.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 07 22:48:23 debian systemd[1]: Failed to start /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
Feb 07 22:48:23 debian systemd[1]: Unit rc-local.service entered failed state.
```

I've tried manually running **sudo bash /home/startup.sh** and it works fine. I've also applied this method on `Ubuntu 14.04` and no errors occurr.

What is the reason behind this failure? How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try following the suggestion printed after `FAILED`?  Namely, what does `systemctl status rc-local.service` report when run as root?

Comment: Concur with @FerencWágner -- please update this answer with the error output. We need those details if we're to be any help.

Comment: @FerencWágner I've updated my question with your required information.

Comment: @Shadur I've updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that your `rc-local.service` is started before `vboxadd-service.service`, but it should run after it. Now, `rc.local` is a SysV thing (where it runs at the very end of the boot process), the compatibility provided by systemd is not perfect (as you can see in your screenshot). You'd probably better off with a custom `home-test.mount` unit like this:

```
[Unit]
Requires=vboxadd-service.service
After=vboxadd-service.service

[Mount]
What=test
Where=/home/test
Type=vboxsf

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

Then `systemctl enable home-test.mount`, remove the `/home/startup.sh` call from `/etc/rc.local` and test the new setup with a reboot.

Warning: I've got zero experience with VirtualBox and very litte with mount units. But you get the idea.

Comment: Big thanks for your answer! I've tested your method and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your file in:

```
/etc/init.d/
```

And then you have to change it to an executable file by:

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/myscript
```

if this does not run you have to create a symlink to:

```
/etc/rc.d/

ln -s /etc/init.d/myscript /etc/rc.d/
```

Please note that on latest Debian, this will not work as your script have to be LSB compliant (provide, at least, the following actions: start, stop, restart, force-reload, and status): https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts

Comment: It doesn't work. A similar error occurred on boot, `[FAILED] Failed to start LSB: Start daemon at boot time`.