# How to mount shared folder from VirtualBox at boot time in Debian

Tags: debian, virtualbox

I know there are many questions already about this problem, but all the solutions that people came up with don't work for me. Personally I took the `/etc/fstab` approach. This is how the content of the file looks like

```
david@debian:~$ sudo cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=e5de59a3-0619-47f9-9a08-858e1e4f6415 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=b9140523-9685-48c4-a870-3604a8f58788 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
GitHub-VM       /home/david/Documents   vboxsf  uid=david,gid=david,dmode=774,fmode=664     0   0
```

Where:

- GitHub-VM: is the folder that I'm sharing from my host system (macOS)
- /home/david/Documents: is the folder on the VirtualMachine (Debian 8)

Of course I didn't forget to force the `vboxsf` kernel module to be loaded at boot time.

```
david@debian:~$ sudo cat /etc/modules
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
vboxsf
```

Sadly, after log-in in, my Document folder is not mapped to the host folder :(. What am I missing?

Comment: DId you try http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260481/debian-8-run-scripts-after-boot/260622#260622 as well?

Comment: That answer is poorly explained can't make much sense of it. If you could maybe edit it to make it more clear, than I could try :)

Comment: I gave a specific answer instead.

Comment: Can you mount manually?

Comment: With Debian host (don't know for MacOSX), the user running virtual-box on the host has to be in group `vboxusers`, if not virtual box works fine, except for shared folders.

Comment: Yes manually I do it like this `mount -t vboxsf GitHub-VM /home/username/Documents -o uid= username -o gid=username`

Answer (score 2):

The mount must happen after `vboxadd-service.service` is started. Systemd v220 has special [`fstab` options](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/89) for this, but unless you use backports, with the jessie version you have to create a custom mount unit instead. Put the following in `/etc/systemd/system/home-david-Documents.mount`:

```
[Unit]
Requires=vboxadd-service.service
After=vboxadd-service.service

[Mount]
What=GitHub-VM
Where=/home/david/Documents
Type=vboxsf

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

remove the corresponding line from `fstab`, `systemctl enable home-david-Documents.mount` and reboot.

Check your boot log and `systemctl status home-david-Documents.mount` if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Another way in /etc/fstab `GitHub-VM       /home/david/Documents  vboxsf x-systemd.automount,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmode=774,fmode=664`

`update-initramfs -u -k all` Reboot

sorry correction wrong maschine.

Comment: This works really great, and after running `systemctl daemon-reload`, somehow automagically create the associated systemd service,

Comment: This worked in getting me past boot but unfortunately, the folder was mounted owned by `root`, so I need to find some way to fix it...